# Hadoop jobs not killed

Tags: exception, configuration, hadoop, jobs

My jobs have some exception before map-reduce steps, but jobs are not getting killed. How to configure hadoop such that jobs get killed after exception?

Invoking Main class now

Heart beat
Heart beat

Invocation of Main class completed

Oozie Launcher ends

stderr logs

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: Unknown host specified )
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:577)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:792)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:815)
    at com.seven.crcs.export.dao.ReportDAOImpl.recreateReportEntity(ReportDAOImpl.java:151)
    at com.seven.crcs.export.dao.ReportDAOImpl.saveActiveUserCount(ReportDAOImpl.java:93)
    at com.seven.crcs.export.ReportJdbcExporter.saveActiveUserCount(ReportJdbcExporter.java:55)
    at com.seven.dataprocessor.oc.jobs.reports.export.day.ExportDailyUserReducer.exportUserCounts(ExportDailyUserReducer.java:32)
    at com.seven.dataprocessor.oc.jobs.reports.export.ExportActiveUser
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: Unknown host specified )
```

And

```
2013-02-28 06:06:46,487 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201302270945_0181_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
2013-02-28 06:07:00,600 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201302270945_0181_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
2013-02-28 06:07:16,650 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201302270945_0181_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
2013-02-28 06:07:31,731 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201302270945_0181
```

But jobs complete SUCCEEDED

Comment: show exception details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job was actually terminated, but only after 3 failed attempts of the map task as the task ids show:

- attempt_201302270945_0181_r_000000_**0**
- attempt_201302270945_0181_r_000000_**1**
- attempt_201302270945_0181_r_000000_**2**

You can limit the number of maximum attempts for each task either by setting the [parameter](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/mapred-default.html) `mapred.map.max.attempts` to `1` or by using [JobConf#setMaxMapAttempts(int)JobConf#setMaxMapAttempts](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setMaxMapAttempts%28int%29).

This will cause your map task to fail on the first exception and thus terminate your job a little faster.

Comment: I set this parametrs, but that my jobs does not write exception and complete succeeded.

Comment: Try setting the max. percentage of failed map and reduce tasks to 0: `jobConf.setMaxMapTaskFailuresPercent(0)` and `jobConf.setMaxReduceTaskFailuresPercent(0)`. According to the [JavaDoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setMaxMapTaskFailuresPercent(int)) it should mark the job as failed immediately on the first failed map or reduce task.

Comment: I don't use class JobConf, I use class Job.

Comment: `JobConf` extends `Configuration` and can be used when creating an instance of `Job`.

Comment: I cannot use JobConf, i must use only class Job.

Comment: `JobConf` can be used to configure the Job class, so you're still using `Job`. If `JobConf` is blacklisted for you for some reason, you will have to come up with another idea to set the parameters.